When does logistic regression outperform random forests?
Suppose we have a binary classification problem, then two possible statistical methods are logistic and random forests.
From a theoretical point of view, it is clear to me that if we have enough linear relationship between the log odds $\log(\frac{q}{1-q})$ and the features $X_1, ... X_p$ then logistic is the stronger candidate by construction.
However, how can we graphically test whether we actually have this linear relationship? For example, in the linear regression case this is fairly easy to do: we can just plot the target vs the covariables and we have a reasonable understanding of how linear is the relationship between the target and the covariables. But what about the logistic case?

Re: "For example, in the linear regression case this is fairly easy to do: we can just plot the target vs the covariables..." this is only true if $P\leq 2$ :)


However, how can we graphically test whether we actually have this linear relationship?

You could look at residual plots to assess the linearity assumption, but an easier automated approach would be to fit a logistic generalized additive model (GAM) with smooth terms for continuous features (y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), etc).  These smooth terms will automatically chose between linear and non-linear effects in a data-driven manner.  You can visualize the estimated relationships using plot or the visreg or ggeffects R packages.

When does logistic regression outperform random forests?

In general, one method will not always outperform the other. So if the goal of your project is to build an accurate predictive model, you should try both and use the one with the higher generalization accuracy (e.g. measured by cross-validation or bootstrap).  If the accuracy is similar, you could go with logistic regression because it is easier to interpret.
Note given many input features, you should try a regularized logistic regression that performs feature selection, in order to have a fair comparison with random forests which does its own type of feature selection.
